# Cant get body from axios.delete server side

Tags: express, axios

I am having trouble accessing the data I am sending with my axios.delete() function, to do things on the backend.

This is my axios call:

```
export const deleteBooking = (email, bookingObjId) => {
console.log("Parameters are both strings and received properly"
    , email, bookingObjId)
const response = axios.delete(`/users`, 
    {data: {userId: email, bookingId: bookingObjId}})
return response
```

}

This is my code receiving it:

```
bookingRouter.delete('/', async(req, res) => {
body = req.body

console.log("body receives nothing, it's just {}", body)

var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.bookingId)
const deleted = await User.updateOne({email: body.userId},
    {$pull: {'bookings': {'_id':id}}}, {safe: true, multi: true})

res.status(200).json(deleted)
 })
```

I have tried req.params as well, and that doesn't work. This seems like a simple fix but I can't find it after looking for hours. I know it's not anything mongoose or react related though, it can't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I find right after posting this after searching for hours:

```
const response = axios.request({
    method: 'delete',
    url,
    data
})
```

works, as per: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3220#issuecomment-688566578